# zipFile.ExtractToDirectory: destination path directory access denied

Tags: c#, android, android-11

I can't unzip a file in the destination path. Every time I get this error message: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path "/ storage / emulated / 0 / Download / Matrix 08_06.enc' is denied".
In manifest I declared MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and gave the file access permission to the app.
Anyone have an idea on how to fix?

Thank you

Comment: Have you requested the permission beside adding it to Manifest?

Comment: Only declaring in manifest is not enough. But anyhow you dont need it.

Comment: yes i did all this, but the problem persists.

Comment: problem solved. The block was generated by the character '':" included in the file name. The strange thing is that in the Version for Oreo 8.1 this character is quietly accepted!!!